# Adding padding to TiledMap Tile Set not fixing lines appearing in game

Tags: java, libgdx

Using a TiledMap in libGDX, I'm getting lines on my map when the game is resized. I've read the million threads about this and they all say to add padding. I did this and it helps, but it did not fix the issue. Using GDX Texture Packer I created my packed tiled set with the following settings:

[image: Texture Packer Settings]

However, this creates some weird things with some of my textures

[image: Packed Texture Issue]

As you can see, there is a green dot in the top right. The top left also has some extra green. I'm not sure if the padding causes this or not.

In TiledMap, I create a new Tileset with the following settings:

[image: TiledMap Settings]

One of my textures (which is 32x32, the size of one tile) is also displaying strangely:

[image: Bad bush]

As you can see, the bottom and right side of the bush have extra green.

In the end, this causes some issues with some of my textures as described above, and it did not fix the issues with lines appearing in my game. Before they were black lines, but now they are different colors. Here is an example of one issue which I circled. The green dots should not be there.

[image: Bad TiledMap]

Do I have a wrong setting? How can I fix these things?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. What fixed it for me was going into photoshop and packing the tiles myself. I added 4px padding inbetween each tile. Also, make sure the padding is NOT transparent, use a similar color to your tile colors. Like this :

[image: 4px Padding]